# Reducing memory usage of GLScene textures

Tags: opengl, textures, lazarus, glscene

I am using GLScene to view images on planes.

I have a hard time figuring out why a 1.2 megabyte photo uses over 50mb of memory
when loaded to a texture which is applied to a plane.

I have tried setting the Texture Compression to tcHighSpeed since render quality
isn't that important to me, no difference as far as I can see.

When adding an "empty" plane with no texture set to it. it uses 1 to 2 megabytes of memory.

Is this an OpenGL thing or is GLScene very innefficient when it comes to memory management?

Comment: You have too little information for an answer. Saying "a 1.2 mb photo" is actually saying nothing useful at all. If you said the horizontal and vertical size and the bit depth, it would be actual information. You are, just at a guess, using a .jpeg photograph, but again, you really should add that info to your question so that we do not have to guess.

Comment: Refer http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=770639&seqNum=3 for OpenGL texture compression hints. tcStandard = Don't care, tcHighQuality = Nicest, tcHighSpeed = Fastest.  Note that fastest is not equal to smallest. Check that your image isn't persistent, ie, kept in RAM after uploading to the card.